# Accessing IIFE in Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, testing, scope, jasmine

I have a JavaScript "class" that looks like this:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function Calculator() {
    this.currentValue = 0;
  }

  Calculator.prototype.add = true;

  return Calculator;
}());
```

Now I am trying to test this with Jasmine – the `CalculatorSpec.js` looks like this:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var calculator;

  beforeEach(function() {
    calculator = new Calculator();
  });

  describe('Calculator', function() {

    it('should contain a function called "add"', function() {
      expect(calculator.add).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
})();
```

How am I supposed to access `Calculator` inside the Jasmine IIFE?

The files are included in the correct order in the specrunner, so I am sure it's a scope problem.

I already tried passing it to the IIFE as argument, but the problem is that Calculator is not available in global scope I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You somehow have to make `Calculator` globally accessible to be able to test it. (And.. how would you otherwise use it in other code blocks?) The easiest way to do this by assigning the IIFE to a variable:

```
var Calculator = (function() {
  'use strict';

  function Calculator() {
    this.currentValue = 0;
  }

  Calculator.prototype.add = true;

  return Calculator;
}());
```